# Two columns (pounds, kilos) convert and fill opposite column depending on which data is entered.

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to keep two columns of data. One in Pounds and one in Kilos. (1 kilo = 2.204 lbs)

The problem is that when I add a row, it might be in kilos, it might be in pounds. Is there a formula I can use to automatically populate the empty cell based on the one that is filled?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a macro-based solution.  Assume column **A** is LBs and column **B** is KILOs.

Enter the following Event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim AB As Range
    Dim rInt As Range, r As Range
    Set AB = Range("A:B")
    Set rInt = Intersect(Target, AB)
    If rInt Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each r In rInt
        If r.Column = 1 Then
            r.Offset(0, 1).Value = r.Value * 2.204
        Else
            r.Offset(0, -1).Value = r.Value / 2.204
        End If
    Next r
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Answer (score 0):

You can create two extra columns to assist you.

1. Create two columns beside your originals ones
2. For kilos, the formula is =IF(ISBLANK(K17),L17/2.204,K17)
3. For pounds, the formula is =IF(ISBLANK(L17),K17*2.204,L17)

K17 is referring to your cell in the original kilo column and
L17 is referring to your cell in the original pound column. :)